# I want to add a scroll or slider to my menu in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a gui which list two types of things in the menubar. The solution that was found was to limit the number of elements in the context menu to 25  :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% construction menu éléments
function base=CreeMenuElem(noms,base,pref)
global kg4_HndlFig
hm=findobj(kg4_HndlFig,'Tag','Elem0');
delete(get(hm,'children')) %reset du menu éléments
set(hm,'Enable','on') %activation du menu éléments
if pref.CacheElem
    noms=noms(~strncmp(noms,'@',1));    %suppression des éléments cachés
end
n=length(noms);
if pref.LimitMenu,MaxMenus=25;else MaxMenus=30;end
ChOld='';k=base;nm=0;
while (k<=n)
    Ch=noms{k};
    p=strfind(Ch,'::');
    if isempty(p)
        nm=nm+1; if nm>MaxMenus, break, end
        uimenu(hm,...
            'Label',Ch,...
            'Tag','Element',...
            'Callback','kgexec4');
        ChOld='';
    else
        ChNew=Ch(1:p-1);
        if ~strcmp(ChOld,ChNew)
            nm=nm+1; if nm>MaxMenus, break, end
            hb=uimenu(hm,'Label',ChNew);
            ChOld=ChNew;
        end
        uimenu(hb,...
            'Label',Ch,...
            'Tag','Element',...
            'Callback','kgexec4');
    end
    k=k+1;
end
if (base>1)|(k<n)
    uimenu(hm,...
        'Label',sprintf('(éléments %g à %g / %g) Suite...',base,k-1,n),...
        'Separator','on',...
        'Tag','SuiteElements',...
        'Callback','kgexec4');
end
if k>n
    base=1; %retour au début de la liste
else
    base=k;
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% construction menu barres
function base=CreeMenuBarr(noms,base,pref)
global kg4_HndlFig
hm=findobj(kg4_HndlFig,'Tag','Barre0');
delete(get(hm,'children')) %reset du menu barres
set(hm,'Enable','on') %activation du menu barres
noms=noms(2:end);   %suppression de GND
if pref.CacheBarr
    noms=noms(~strncmp(noms,'@',1)); %suppression des noms auto
end
n=length(noms);
if pref.LimitMenu,MaxMenus=25;else,MaxMenus=30;end
bb=min(base+MaxMenus-1,n);  %dernier menu à afficher
for k=base:bb
    uimenu(hm,...
        'Label',noms{k},...
        'Tag','Barre',...
        'Callback','kgexec4' );
end
if (n>MaxMenus) && pref.LimitMenu
    uimenu(hm,'Label',sprintf('(barres %g à %g / %g) Suite...',base,bb,n),...
        'Tag','SuiteBarres', 'Separator','on', 'Callback','kgexec4' );
end
if bb<n, base=bb+1; else base=1; end %retour au début de la liste

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I would like to be able to scroll in these menus instead of using this solution that can be impractical and slow but i don't understand how to add the scroll option. I tried with uicontrol but it never works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
g=figure;
    u=uipanel(g,'backgroundcolor',[1 0 1],'units','pixels','position',[1000 1000 g.InnerPosition(3)-19 1000]);
    uu=findjobj(u);
    j=javax.swing.JScrollPane(uu);
    j.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(j.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    [jj hh]=javacomponent(j,[10 10 g.InnerPosition(3)-20 g.InnerPosition(4)-20],g);
    %components to add to panel
    button=uicontrol(u,'style','pushbutton','units','pixels',...
        'position',[0.1 0.1 100 100],'string','blah');
```

or if that doesnt work this longer method from the MATLAB math works page

**Example** : I wish to create a panel with a variable number of lines and text edit boxes that the user can scroll through to edit. The main window handle is `ptrMainGUI`. I have two subpanels: one for the slider, and one for the content that it will scroll through: `ptrPanelStimParamsParent` and `ptrPanelStimParams`. `intParams` here is the number of lines I'm going to generate. As long as you create `variables ptrMainGUI`, as well as `intParams`, `cellProps`, `cellVals`, `cellComments` for your lines and values to generate in the panel I think it should work.

```
%get main GUI size and define subpanel size
ptrMainGUI.Units = 'pixels';
vecGuiSize = ptrMainGUI.Position;
ptrMainGUI.Units = 'normalized';
dblPanelHeight = 0.2;
dblPanelY = 0.1;
%calculate the total size of the subpanel content
dblTotSize = (intParams+1)*30;
dblRelSize = (dblTotSize/(vecGuiSize(end)*dblPanelHeight))+dblPanelHeight;
%create the panels
ptrPanelStimParamsParent = uipanel('Parent',sFigRE.ptrMainGUI);
set(ptrPanelStimParamsParent,'Position',[0.01 dblPanelY 0.94 dblPanelHeight]);
ptrPanelStimParams = uipanel('Parent',ptrPanelStimParamsParent);
set(ptrPanelStimParams,'Position',[0 0 1 dblRelSize]);
ptrSlider = uicontrol('Style','Slider','Parent',sFigRE.ptrMainGUI,...
    'Units','normalized','Position',[0.94 dblPanelY 0.05 dblPanelHeight],...
    'Value',1,'Callback',{@slider_callback1,ptrPanelStimParams});
%add all variables
vecParamTextPtrs = nan(1,intParams);
vecParamEditPtrs = nan(1,intParams);
for intParam=1:intParams
    vecParamTextPtrs(intParam) = uicontrol(ptrPanelStimParams,'style','text',...
        'Position',[1 (intParams*30)-((intParam-1)*30) 150 25],'String',cellProps{intParam},'FontSize',10);
    vecParamEditPtrs(intParam) = uicontrol(ptrPanelStimParams,'style','edit',...
        'Position',[150 (intParams*30)-((intParam-1)*30) 390 25],'String',cellVals{intParam},'Tooltip',cellComments{intParam},'FontSize',10);
end
%add callback
slider_callback1(ptrSlider,[],ptrPanelStimParams);
```

Now, to scroll properly we'll need to use the following function with some arcane transformations. The `vecSize(end)-1` is to avoid showing an empty block the size of exactly one parent panel:

```
 function slider_callback1(hObject,eventdata,ptrSubPanel)
        vecSize = ptrSubPanel.Position;
        val = get(hObject,'Value');
        dblRealMax = vecSize(end) - 1;
        dblStartY = val*dblRealMax;
        vecSetPanelPos = [0 -dblStartY 1 vecSize(end)];
        set(ptrSubPanel,'Position',vecSetPanelPos);%[from-left from-bottom width height]
    end
```

Comment: thx a lot for i will try those 2 methodes